# issue installing Laravel cashier package on Laravel 7.0

Tags: laravel-7, laravel-cashier

install Laravel cashier package but not install getting error and used PHP version: 7.4.8

**Using version ^13.4 for laravel/cashier
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update laravel/cashier
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
Problem 1
- laravel/cashier 13.x-dev requires illuminate/contracts ^8.0 -> found illuminate/contracts[v8.0.0, ..., 8.x-dev] but it conflicts with another require.
- laravel/cashier v13.4.0 requires illuminate/console ^8.0 -> found illuminate/console[v8.0.0, ..., 8.x-dev] but it conflicts with another require.
- Root composer.json requires laravel/cashier ^13.4 -> satisfiable by laravel/cashier[v13.4.0, 13.x-dev].
Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to provide cashier version for laravel 7

```
composer require laravel/cashier ^12
```

this may work for you